# What's the secret to getting screen sharing to work with Messages in OS X 10.11?

Tags: messages, screen-sharing

I have a client who is only moderately comfortable in Xcode, and regularly has problems building the app I'm developing for him, or git conflicts, or other things that are very painful to figure out over the phone or via chat.

Up until last week we were using the "Ask to share Screen" feature in messages. I changed my iCloud password, and suddenly this option is dimmed. I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do in order to enable screen sharing.

What are the requirements on both ends? What kind of account do we need to be logged in with? iCloud? AIM? What else do I need to do? This is making me nuts.

Comment: Did you update your iCloud password in iMessages on the Mac?  A similar thing happened to me and it was because this setting wasn't updated.

Comment: Use Chrome Remote Desktop!!!